# Writing my first blender Addon and I am confused on these string keywords

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I am currently writing my first blender addon and I have opened up one of those sample templates as a reference. I have noticed that if I want to create a button to make it appear I have to use these default string keywords. Eg. `frame_start`, `frame_end` or `render.render`. My question is, can I make my own custom slider or button that doesn't use these predefined string keywords?

At first, I thought these were replaceable strings but if I mistype just one letter the entire button disappears. Basically, I want to create a slider or a button that says "Number of final output images" in the box itself instead of "End Frame:" or "Start Frame: " how should I proceed?

Comment: Worth mentioning that these "strings" are attribute names. `ob.foo` is the equivalent of `getattr(ob, "foo")`  andsimilarly with  `ob.foo = 3` using  `setattr(ob, "foo", 3)`.   (also the test `has_foo = hasattr(ob, "foo")`  Using the attribute setters and getters is very common (and basic)  in python.  The UI elements are similar, eg `layout.prop(ob, "foo")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example "strings" that you show belong to two different categories, `frame_start` and `frame_end` are property names while `render.render` is an operator name. The properties will display as a number that you can edit while the operator will show as a button that will perform an action when clicked.

The strings that you use need to match an existing property or operator for them to work, an operator is identified by it's `bl_idname` property. You can specify a property or operator name and have a different string shown by passing a `text` paramater.

```
row.prop(scene, 'frame_start', text='adjust this here')
row.operator('render.render', text='This is my render button')
```

To create extra properties that are only used by your addon, you can use [custom properties](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html), which you should create in your addons `register()` function.

```
class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    ...
    def draw(self, context):
        row = self.layout.row()
        row.prop(context.scene, 'my_prop')

def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.my_prop = bpy.props.IntProperty()
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyPanel)
```

For operators, you can [make your own](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html) and then use the `bl_idname` that you set in your operator class to show a button for it. If no `text` paramater is passed, an operators `bl_label` property is shown on the button.